# How to search for a string with one double quote with git grep in Windows cmd

Tags: windows, git, cmd, grep, escaping

The problem is that strings with two qoutes are searched well. But! I want to look for a string `"Agent` (one double quote!) inside my repo on cmd in Windows. So I having this:

`git grep "\"Agent\"" > 1.txt` (it works! all strings with `"Agent"` was found)

`git grep "\"Agent" > 1.txt` (error! `fatal: ambiguous argument '>': unknown revision...`)

Any ideas how to properly escape?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Git CMD or Windows *cmd* console, you can use `^` to escape the `"` inside the terminal:

```
git grep ""^""Agent" > 1.txt
```

In Git Bash, you can simply use

```
git grep '"Agent' > 1.txt
```

See this text I made on my data with `"Regex` pattern:

[image]

Comment: Both of them are in fact not only looking for `"Agent` but also for some (!) of `Agent` encounters. Like for example both of them returns lines which includes `userAgent` and `'Agent`. This means your commands do not look up for a double quote...

Comment: @yakunins I double-checked and edited the answer, please check the above.

Comment: Thank you! `git grep ""^""Agent" > 1.txt` does the trick!

Comment: So `"_"^""_"` matches `_"_` in CMD! Amazing.

Comment: It does not "match", this is how the `_"_` string can be defined in a CMD command.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting so here are my findings in CMD and Git Bash if you will use just one quote whether it is a single quote or double quote the command will break and bash will intercept it as 2 different commands. This is not only in the case of `git grep` but an `echo` will also have the same behavior.

[image]
Here you can see that I'm using syntax similar to yours in `echo` and it's not writing into the file just printing the next whole line

[image]
Now when I have added the closing quotes echo is working perfectly and writing into the file.

Now if you want to print a single quote you would have to use double quotes as starting and ending quotes and vice versa. [click here for reference](https://linuxize.com/post/echo-command-in-linux-with-examples/#:%7E:text=To%20print%20a%20single%20quote,use%20the%20ANSI%2DC%20Quoting%20.&text=Display%20a%20message%20containing%20special,interpretation%20of%20the%20escape%20characters.).

[image]
Now according to this documentation, wrapping a single quote in double-quotes works and this works in the case of `grep` as well.

But its reverse (wrapping double quotes in single quotes) doesn't work in windows CMD this might be because bash is intercepting double quotes ("). But you can use `git bash` and below will work properly.
[image]